# Google maps markers are getting bigger when running application on different screen size

Tags: java, android, kotlin, maps, markers

I have app which makes different size markers on google maps (Android).
Recently, when I tested my application on hdpi screen device, when it appears on this device markers are huge, like 10x bigger than xxhdpi version device I have used before.  I want markers to be similar on all screen size devices.

Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

When you add a marker to your map, you can change its size like that:

```
marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(resource, px, px, false)));
```

where resource is your marker bitmap, and px, px is width and height in pixel.

Comment: i am doing it that way, still when i am giving same width and height to createScaledBitmap function, its big on one screen and small on other screen. My goal is to make them same size on all screens

Comment: Are you converting dp to px before setting marker size?

Comment: i am converting px to dp, ie getting density value, and then dividing like px/density, and giving result value to bitmap creator as Integer. Is that wrong?

Comment: As I know, you should pass px value to createScaledBitmap, px = assume_dp * density
for example if you want marker size 24*24 dp, set  assume_dp = 24

Comment: Or you can convert from dp to px using:

Resources r = getResources();
float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, assume_dp, r.getDisplayMetrics());

Comment: none of the above helped. when i had big markers, they are even bigger now.